# php regex how to differentiate whole name into 2 names

Tags: php, regex

I had  string like "John John James James", where John John  is one name and James James is another name, how do I differentiate them as 2 names using regex code?

I am using this regex code: `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*$`, but it considers everything as a whole name, but i dont want like that.

Comment: is it always two words separated by space?

Comment: Are the lengths fixed?Like only 2 words or something like that?

Comment: there is no rule as 2 words every name

Comment: Regex works on patterns, to be able to use Regex to split your string up you need to define a name as a recurring pattern, such as it's always two whole words, then the next two whole words are the next name etc. Without some sort of pattern (it can be a complex pattern) there's nothing you can do with regex

Comment: If the names are always the maybe start with something like this `~([A-Z][a-z]+)\s+\1~`. As noted though a clearer pattern would be good. This regex will identify double names next to each other.

Answer (score -1):

`(\S+\s+\S+)\s+(\S+\s+\S+)` for the simplest cases: https://regex101.com/r/eQ3oY8/1

For more complex name combinations you have to define some more strict rules. For example, the string `George Henry Martin Luther King` would be hard to split unless you define some more rules. It may be either `George Henry` + `Martin Luther King` or `George Henry Martin` + `Luther King`.

Comment: That doesn't do any more than two names in a row. What if there are more than two in the string? What if you don't know how many will be in a string? `/(\S+\s+\S+)/g` works better than what you have.